# How to save "printf("\\n");" in php variable

Tags: php

I have a string (a c code) in a vairable. I want to print it php. But i don't why everything after double quotes in not printing.. pls help. Below is the code.

```
$answer_something='printf("\\n")';
echo $answer_something;

//OUTPUT: printf(
//WHAT I WANT TO PRINT IS printf("\\n");
```

Comment: You want to print `\\n`? If yes, use single quotes `printf('\\n');` - Please be more precise; your question is unclear.

Comment: What does POST have to do with this? I can't understand this question at all.

Comment: I re-read your question a few more times; try `$var = "printf(\"\\n\";)"; echo $var;` will print `printf("\n";)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think it should be `$var = "printf(\"\\\\n\");"; echo $var;`

Comment: @Brandin You're right; I stand corrected. I thought I had that extra slash. +1

Comment: I don't want to print \\n. What i need to print is “printf(”\\n“);”. The entire code including printf

Comment: @GijoVarghese Did you not try Alvaro's answer below?

Comment: Why are you guys down voting my post? Its after a lot of searching i posted it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP syntax for strings is explained in the [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) chapter of the manual. To produce static strings with code samples into variables I'd go for [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc):

```
<?php

$str = <<<'EOD'

    printf("\\n");

    You can write almost anything you want. No 'escaping' "needed" \r \n \

EOD;

var_dump($str);
```

Of course, this does not apply if you read information from [the $_POST superglobal array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php): the array will automatically contain whatever the user submitted.

Comment: I noticed you added the var_dump after (I didn't see it till I reloaded, since I'd gotten an error). I was going to say that it's worth noting that there should be at least a carriage return after `EOD;` otherwise it would throw `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or heredoc end (T_END_HEREDOC) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN)`

Answer (score 0):

How about using:

```
$x = 'printf("\\\\n");';
echo $x;
```

I suppose this is for some kind of trivia / questionnaire. You have to escape each backslash with 2 backslashes.

You can check the output here: http://ideone.com/fFvb28

Comment: I always thought you escape a backslash with one backslash, e.g. if you want \ you escape it and get "\\"

Comment: If you want to output one backslash you escape it with 2. If you want to output 2 you have to escape it with 4.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$answer_something = $_POST['option'];

if($answer_something == '\\n'){
    printf("\\n");
}
```